# Decarboxylation of 2‐cyano‐2‐cyclohexylideneacetic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, resonance, elimination, nitriles

2‐Cyano‐2‐cyclohexylideneacetic acid (**1**) is heated and $\ce{CO2}$ is lost:

[[image]

Why is this not formed?

[image: 2‐cyclohexylideneacetonitrile]

In other words, why do π-electrons move into the ring?

Comment: As drawn, the reaction will not work. Conceptually, if you lose H+ from -CO2H and then lose CO2 you are left with the anion of the nitrile. Add the proton on the anion and you have CO2 and 2-cyclohexylacetonitrile. There is no double bond.

Comment: Oh I see what has happened. I think someone editing the question has copied one of the molecules incorrectly. I am changing that now.

Comment: You need to ping @user55119, or else they won't get a notification.

Comment: This reaction is an Organic Syntheses prep;http://orgsyn.org/Result.aspx?ga=pa KOH was not used. Now you can work on a mechanism. Notice that ammonium acetate is still present during the decarboxylation. BTW, I believe this very question was asked previously on ChemSE.